# Optimization with Lagrange multipliers

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I am new to Lagrange multipliers.
Could some one show me how to minimize the following function:
\begin{align}
f(x,y)=ax+by-\sqrt{cxy}
\end{align}
subject to:
\begin{align}
0 &\le x\\
0 &\le y \\
ax &\le k y
\end{align}

Comment: Since the variables are positive, it'll be convenient to define $x=z^2$ and $y=w^2$ to avoid the square roots. Also, those last two constraints are peculiar: what is $k$?

Comment: Can you at least setup Lagrange's equations?

Comment: @Semiclassical k is some constant. Say greater than 1.

Comment: @AlexR. No.I can't. Sorry. I newer seen Lagrange optimization with inequalities

Comment: The reason it's odd that you've really got two cases, since either $a x \leq b y \leq ky$ or $ax \leq k y \leq by$. (And since the former case is equivalent to the latter for $k=b$, you might as well on $ax\leq k y$.)

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will drop one constrain

Comment: when you have an inequality in the constraint, you should do the following: first, find all extrema and only use the ones that meet the restriction (are inside the constrain) using the typical method (see the critial points of $\nabla f(x)=0$); and then search the extrema on the restriction, using LaGrange multipliers and $ax=ky$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

When a constrain in an inequality ($\leq,\geq$) you should do the following:

1. Find the extrema of the function, assuming there's no contrain, and retain all points that meet the constrain
2. Then, use Lagrange multipliers to find all extrema in the contrain.

If we proceed that way in this problem, we'll have the following:

---

1) Let's find the critical points of $f(x,y)$ that meet $ax<ky$:
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\nabla f(x,y)&=&\vec{0}\\
\Rightarrow a-\frac{\sqrt{cy}}{2\sqrt{x}}&=&0\\
b-\frac{\sqrt{cx}}{2\sqrt{y}}&=&0\\
&&\\
\Rightarrow 2a\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{cy}&=&0\\
-\sqrt{cx}+2b\sqrt{y}&=&0\\
\end{array}$$

Using substitution $u=\sqrt{x},\,v=\sqrt{y}$:
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\Rightarrow 2au-\sqrt{c}v&=&0\\
-\sqrt{c}u+2bv&=&0\\
\end{array}$$

The linear equation system has determinant $4ab-c$. You'll need conditions on $a,b,c$ to verify if the system has only one solution $4ab\neq c$) or infinite ($4ab=c$).

a) If the system has only one solution, it is obviously $x=y=0$.

b) If the system has infinite solutions, the solutions are given by the base $(\frac{2a}{\sqrt{c}},1)_{u,v}=(\frac{4a^2}{c},1)_{x,y}$ intersecting the region $ax<ky$.

---

2) Now we use Lagrange multipliers with $ax-ky=0$:
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
L(x,y,\lambda)&=&f(x,y)-\lambda g(x,y)\\
&=&ax+by-\sqrt{cxy}-\lambda(ax-ky)\\
&=&ax+by-\sqrt{cxy}-\lambda ax-\lambda ky
\end{array}$$

Then
$$\begin{array}{rclcc}
\nabla L(x,y,\lambda)&=&0&&\\
\Rightarrow \nabla f(x,y)&=&\lambda\nabla g(x,y)&&\\
\Rightarrow a-\frac{\sqrt{cy}}{2\sqrt{x}}&=&\lambda a&&(1)\\
b-\frac{\sqrt{cx}}{2\sqrt{y}}&=&-\lambda k&&(2)\\
ax-ky&=&0&&(3)\\
\end{array}$$

Using $(3)$ in $(2)$,
$$\begin{array}{rclcc}
2a(1-\lambda)\sqrt{x}&=&\sqrt{c}\sqrt{y}&&(4)\\
2\biggl(b+\lambda\frac{ax}{y}\biggr)\sqrt{y}&=&\sqrt{c}\sqrt{x}&&(5)\\
\end{array}$$

I think you can solve the equation system from here.

---

I hope you find this useful. I also think that you would need to impose some assumptions on $a,b,c,k$ to get "closed" solutions. Good luck!